# 'react-native' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file when I already have python,npm,nodejs and jdk

Tags: react-native

I am trying to install react native in my laptop. For this, I have already intalled **NodeJS, react-native CLI, NPM, python 3.8 and JDK.** This is my cmd image when I typed javac and other commands for checking if everything is installed or not. [image: This is my Command Prompt image.]

What is the error?

Comment: did you install react-native-cli globaly, with -g flag. try again with `npm i -g react-native-cli`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have followed the old installation documentation please follow the new installation documentation
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started

> If you previously installed a global react-native-cli package, please remove it as it may cause unexpected issues. `npm uninstall -g react-native-cli`

then use new `npx` to install new react native applications `npx react-native init NewProject`